# Modify view if one dropdown is selected, other dropdowns to be disabled

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, yii2

I have a form where i am assigning some equipments to an user. I want to assign only one equipment to one user because i have a start date and end date. I want if i select some display from dropdown, the phone and laptop to freeze and to be selected default none. I also want if i select phone for ex, display and laptop to freeze.I found somewhere that it can be made with javascript, but i don't know how. **If you can guide me or give me a proper example i would appreciate.I am new to js.**

Here is my form :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\User;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\UserEquipmentMapping */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

#print_r($userquery);die;

?>

<div class="user-equipment-mapping-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')
            ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($usermodel, 'id', 'username'))?>
            
    <?= $form->field($model, 'laptop_id')
            ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($laptopmodel, 'id', 'laptop_series'))?>
            
    <?= $form->field($model, 'phone_id')
            ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($phonemodel, 'id', 'phone_series'))?>
    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'display_id')
            ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($displaymodel, 'id', 'display_series'))?>



    <?=$form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
]);?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'stop_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
]);?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**Thank you for any suggestions**

UPDATE : But still not working, i have tried for the first 2 dropdowns at least to test.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\User;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\UserEquipmentMapping */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

#print_r($userquery);die;

?>
    




<div class="user-equipment-mapping-form">
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#dropDown1").val())
      $("#dropDown2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   else
      $("#dropDown2").removeAttr("disabled");

   if($("#dropDown2").val())
      $("#dropDown1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else
      $("#dropDown1").removeAttr("disabled");

   $($("#dropDown1").on("change", function(){
       if($(this).val())
          $("#dropDown2").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
       else
          $("#dropDown2").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
   $($("#dropDown2").on("change", function(){
       if($(this).val())
          $("#dropDown1").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
       else
          $("#dropDown1").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
});
    </script>
    
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    
    
    <?php 
    $userData=ArrayHelper::map($usermodel,'id','username');
    echo $form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList($userData, ['prompt'=>'Select...'], array("id" => 'dropDown1'));
    ?>
    
    
            
    <?php 
    $laptopData=ArrayHelper::map($laptopmodel,'id','laptop_series');
    echo $form->field($model, 'laptop_id')->dropDownList($laptopData, ['prompt'=>'Select...'], array("id" => 'dropDown2'));
    ?>  

    <?php 
    $phoneData=ArrayHelper::map($phonemodel,'id','phone_series');
    echo $form->field($model, 'phone_id')->dropDownList(
                                    $phoneData, 
                                    ['prompt'=>'Select...']);
    ?>
    
    <?php 
    $displayData=ArrayHelper::map($displaymodel,'id','display_series');
    echo $form->field($model, 'display_id')->dropDownList(
                                    $displayData, 
                                    ['prompt'=>'Select...']);
    ?>


    <?=$form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
]);?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'stop_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'language' => 'en',
        'value' => date('yyyy/mm/dd', strtotime('+7 days')),
        'readonly' => true,
        #'disabled' => true,
        #'size' => 'lg',
        #'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectati data'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            #'orientation' => 'top right',
            'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'todayBtn' => true,
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
]);?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: i suggest you usign ajax request to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdowns - add `onchange` function and class `equipment`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'laptop_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($laptopmodel, 'id', 'laptop_series'), ['prompt'=>'Select...', 'onchange' => 'setEquipment(this)', 'class' => 'equipment'])?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'phone_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($phonemodel, 'id', 'phone_series'), ['prompt'=>'Select...', 'onchange' => 'setEquipment(this)', 'class' => 'equipment'])?>
    
<?= $form->field($model, 'display_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($displaymodel, 'id', 'display_series'), ['prompt'=>'Select...', 'onchange' => 'setEquipment(this)', 'class' => 'equipment'])?>
```

js

```
function setEquipment(el){
        var equipment_elements = $('.equipment');
        if($(el).val() != "") {
            $.each(equipment_elements, function (key, value) { //disable all elements
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            });
            $(el).attr('disabled', false); //enable current element
        }else{
            $.each(equipment_elements, function (key, value) { //enable all elements
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            });
        }
    }
```